# First Order Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I would like some help to check my solution for the translation of a sentence into predicate logic.

The sentence is given as:

```
Every patient was seen by a cardiologist
```

I thought of this:

$ ∀x∃y(P(x) ∧  S(x, C(y)) $

where:

```
P(x): x is a patient
S(x, y): x was seen by y
C(y): y is a cardiologist
```

Additionally, is it allowed to add a $C(y)$ inside another function as I did above in $S(x, C(y))$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your statement would imply everyone is a patient.

Comment: But, the "Every patient" how would you represent?

Comment: "If $x$ is a patient then he/she was seen by a cardiologist" - do you think that this statement is logically equivalent to the one you have written?

Comment: Would it make sense this way? ∀x∃y(S(P(x), C(y)) @user170039

Comment: To answer your last question: no, it is not allowed in first order logic to give a proposition as an argument to a predicate. Your formula is not well-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statements does not imply "Every patient was seen by a cardiologist".

It implies something like "Everyone is patient and a cardiologist sees them".

The reason is using "$\land$" in this, you should use $\implies$ like this:

$\forall x \exists y \big(P(x) \implies (C(y) \land S(x,y)) \big)$

This implies that" Everyone who is a patient was seen by one who is a cardiologist".

Comment: Neat. Thanks for this explanation!